# mysql select based on maths on values linked

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to output the top x items in my database based on a value of linked 'tags'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f23ad2

The function I'm currently using (note: :userId is the id from the user table):

SELECT
  item.id,
  item.name
FROM
  item
LEFT JOIN
  item_tag
    ON
  item.id = item_tag.item
LEFT JOIN
  tag
    ON
  item_tag.tag = tag.id
LEFT JOIN
  user_tag
    ON
  user_tag.user = :userId
    AND
  item_tag.tag = user_tag.tag
LEFT JOIN
  item_tag_rating
    ON
  item_tag.tag = item_tag_rating.tag
    AND
  TRUNCATE(user_tag.val,0) = item_tag_rating.user_tag
ORDER BY
  tag_rating DESC
LIMIT 10

The idea is that the `user_tags` table will tell you the user's `tag_level` (1-5) or if they don't currently have one use a default of 3 and based on that you get the value for that level in the `item_tags` table.

If there are 3 tags for instance you end up with 3 decimal numbers (percentage rating converted to decimal) which is then combined to get an overall percentage rating for the item.  I then want to use that overall percentage number to output the top x items.

Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: How these tables related to each others?

Comment: clarified in description

Comment: Please enter some example data. Preferable an SQL Fiddle.

Comment: added sqlfiddle

Comment: Can you add an example of how you've tried to query the data in the fiddle?

Comment: @BlackThorn - Have you read the stuff in http://stackoverflow.com/help yet? Of particular relevance, is the section devoted to asking a good question. With that said, it's much clearer now that you've entered some raw data into the sql fiddle. What seems unfortunately to be a glaring omission is the actual output you expect. I realise you've expressed it in english - this is a good accompaniment to some actual data, but often falls short of expressing what is wanted, ultimately leading to poor answers that are difficult to furnish. The more explicit the request, the easier it is to fulfil. ;)

Comment: @calcinai right now the output is a mix of mysql and php so difficult to display.  I'm selecting all items and then working out the value for the tags.  I'm not sure how I can do it as part of one call hence the question.

Comment: @enhzflep yes, it is handier with the data.  I'm not sure how to express the expected output in anything other than english though, would you have a format you would be looking for in particular?

Comment: think I've added it correctly to the fiddle.  I'm looking for the order to be based on the total tag rating based on the multiple tags combined as outlined

Comment: @BlackThorn - well, whenever I'm doing something like this, I make a table in excel or whatever is easiest to work with tabular data. In it, I place all the data that I would expect to get back for each row of the query results, along with the table & column-name of it's source. As it stands, I don't know how many columns you expect back, nor what you want them to contain. I do understand that you'd like to limit the results, so that you only get a portion of the data - this takes care of how many rows. But still, what's expected in each row is unknown. (continued)

Comment: So, since you need to do a join on some tables, we (you) need to work out which columns from each are needed and which column in one table will be used to identify the corresponding row from another table. There's no need to do this for more than 1 row. Perhaps this will help explain the relationships I'm speaking of: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: @enhzflep I see where the confusion is.  I added the function I'm currently using to the fiddle but it doesn't appear to have stored it if it even can (first time using that service) I will add it to the description and it might make a bit more sense :)  The part that is missing is that I want to also output the total rating for the item (the combined rating of each tag linked to it into one decimal rating)